# List comprehension suggestion

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
>>> odd,even=[ ],[ ]
>>> [even.append(x) if x%2==0 else odd.append(x) for x in range(51)]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> odd
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49]
```

my question: is it possible to separate the odd and even numbers in the list comprehension statement even without declaring the `odd, even = [], []` at the beginning?

Comment: Using a list comprehension for sideeffects is unpythonic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version: for me elegnat,compact and fine to understand

```
even,odd = [],[]
for x in range(51): x%2 and even.append(x) or odd.append(x)
```

Comment: thats pretty nice solution. when i ask question I always get more than I could even thought.

Comment: This is short, but readable should always be preferred over short.

Comment: @Lattyware is just a matter of habits. Since I always write them down in this way, for me this is readable and compact but i got your point and is a valid notice

Comment: I don't like this use of `and`/`or` when you can do this and it is even shorter: `for x in range(51): (odd if x%2 else even).append(x)`

Comment: @jamylak i din't told that is the best or shorter way ... Just provided an alternative and working solution.

Comment: @jamylak ps.: really enojoy your alternative way, just to be clear

Comment: @DonCallisto I know what you mean :D I think I will post my way as well.

Answer (score 7):

Best to just loop once. It's 6 lines, but they are *fast* lines

```
odd, even=[ ], [ ]
for x in range(51):
    if x%2:
        odd.append(x)
    else:
        even.append(x)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
even,odd = [],[]
for x in range(51): 
    (odd if x%2 else even).append(x)
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider this

```
evens = [i for i in xrange(1,1000) if i % 2]
odds = [i for i in xrange(1,1000) if i % 2 != 0]
```

Comment: thanks,but i want to know if it is possible to combine them in 1 statement

Comment: Look bellow that is one statement.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> even, odd = [[x for x in range(51) if x%2 == 0], [x for x in range(51) if x%2 == 1]]
>>> even
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50]
>>> odd
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49]
```

I wouldn't recommend this method, but here's a way you could do it with "only one loop" I guess:

```
>>> even, odd = zip(*[(x, x + 1) for x in range(0, 51, 2)])
>>> even
(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50)
>>> odd
(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51)
```

Answer (score 3):

I like to draw attention to `itertools` and in particular, the [itertools recipes](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) in the Python help. Here we can use the `partition` function (backported to Python 2.7)

```
from itertools import tee, ifilter, ifilterfalse

def partition(pred, iterable):
    'Use a predicate to partition entries into false entries and true entries'
    # partition(is_odd, range(10)) --> 0 2 4 6 8   and  1 3 5 7 9
    t1, t2 = tee(iterable)
    return ifilterfalse(pred, t1), ifilter(pred, t2)

def is_odd(n):
    return bool(n%2)

evens, odds = partition(is_odd, range(51))

print list(evens)
print list(odds)
```

In fact, the example in the docstring explains exactly this case use. It returns iterators and hence the need for using `list` when printing.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a simplified problem using numbers for convenience, then my answer isn't relevant, but the simplest way to do what you have requested is really:

```
>>> odd, even = range(1, 51, 2), range(0, 51, 2)
```

Which gives you:

```
>>> list(odd)
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49]
>>> list(even)
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50]
```

Comment: my intention was to learn more about list comprehension statement,but urs one is a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Tackling the generic problem:

> Given a predicate function `predicate` returning either `True` or `False` when given an object, separate a list into two sublists according to the predicate while preserving the order

Then we may use a the fact that the `sorted` funciton is *stable*, so if we sort with `predicate` as key, the list is effectively split in two at an unknown point while preserving order within each part, with values for which predicate is `False` to the left and values for which it is `True` to the right.

Now we can use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with the same key to split at this unknown point.

```
from itertools import groupby

predicate = lambda x: x % 2 == 0

def group_by_predicate(L, pred):
    return [list(i) for k, i in groupby(sorted(L, key=pred), key=pred)]

odd, even = group_by_predicate(range(51), predicate)
```

This will work even if the values for which `predicate` is `True` are not evenly spaced... say for instance if `predicate` is `True` for prime numbers.